How can I install htop, nohup, or other linux CLI utilities on Intel based Core i5 QNAP NAS running QTS 5+?
I would like to have available on my Intel-based QNAP NAS utilities nohup and htop for SSH sessions to my QNAP NAS with SSH scripts that must run for long times in background, but QTS 5.1 does not supply these basic utilities.
Entware used to be available but seems to not be an option now.

Since other routes have been closed off, I found this method to work, at least for me.
In Windows 11 I have WSL2 Ubuntu 22 VM. That comes with nohup and htop, which are all not included in the simple QTS linux. However, the simple binary executables from my WSL2 linux seem to run fine in QTS5.1 linux. I think I can trust these binaries.
In WSL2 linux shell, I located nohup with
which nohup at /usr/bin/nohup. I copied this binary to my NAS with BitviseSSH ftp and put it in ~/bin, made
it executable, and added ~/bin to my PATH in .bashrc.
Tried it and it runs:
  ~/bin$ nohup
  nohup: missing operand
  Try 'nohup --help' for more information.

For htop, I needed to also copy some missing shared libraries.
After I ran htop, it complained about missing libraries.
To find out what was missing, I ran ldd htop on the NAS, and it told me libncursesw.so.6 and libtinfo.so.6 were missing.
In WSL2, I rand ldd htop to located its libraries:
root@tobi-joule-amd:~# ldd /usr/bin/htop
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd20489000)
    libncursesw.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6 (0x00007f0f97b22000)
    libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f0f97af2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0f979a3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0f977b1000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0f977ab000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0f97ba4000)

I copied the missing .so to the ~/bin folder, together with htop, and added ~/bin  to my (new) LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my .bashrc:
PATH="~/bin:$PATH"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/bin:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Now I have htop:


Note that with ssh from terminator color terminal, I get "Error opening terminal: xterm-256color." from htop
